# Symfony 3 anonymous route

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony-3.4

I have a problem with creation anonymous route in my project. I have almost all bundle protected but some routes I need to make accessible externally. I tried many hours how it should be but seems that I am missing something. I am attaching config files.

Config.yml

```
security:
    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: consensus

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
        AppBundle\Domain\Customer\Customer: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_CUSTOMER:            ROLE_USER
        ROLE_CUSTOMER_CONFIRMED:  ROLE_CUSTOMER
        ROLE_ACCOUNT:             ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:               ROLE_ACCOUNT
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:         [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        customer:
            id: app.customer.user_provider

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false


        api_customers_login:
            pattern: ^/api/customers/login
            anonymous: true

        api_login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                provider:                 customer
                check_path:               /api/login
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api:
            provider: customer
#            pattern:   ^/api(?!/doc|/conventions/*|/speakers/*|/events/*|/workshops/*|/agendadays/*)
            pattern:   ^/api(?!/doc|/public/*)
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
#                    - app.customer.jwt_token_authenticator

        shop:
            provider: customer
            pattern: ^/shop

            form_login:
                provider: customer
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                use_referer: true
                login_path: shop_login
                check_path: shop_login_check
#                check_path: shop_login
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path:            shop_default_index

            logout:
                path:       shop_logout
                target:     shop_default_index
#                handlers:   [user.logout_handler]

            anonymous:    true

            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
#                lifetime: 86400 # 1 day
                lifetime: 3600 # 1 day
                path:     /shop
                name:     shop_remember

        main:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            pattern: ^/(?!/api)

#           #deprecated
            entry_point: user.entry_point

            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                use_referer: true
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path:            homepage

            logout:
                path:       fos_user_security_logout
                target:     homepage
                handlers:   [user.logout_handler]

            anonymous:    true
            switch_user:  true

            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 3600 # 1 day
                path:     /
                name:     main_remember

      access_control:

            - { path: ^/[0-9]+/agenda/feed.xml,   roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

            - { path: ^/api/login$,             roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/api/customers/login$,   roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/api/public,             roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/api,                    roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
            - { path: ^/api/doc,                roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ACCOUNT] }

            - { path: ^/shop/.+/login$,         roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/shop/.+/customer/email-confirm,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/shop/.+/customer,       roles: ROLE_CUSTOMER }
            - { path: ^/shop/.+/cart/checkout,  roles: ROLE_CUSTOMER_CONFIRMED }
            - { path: ^/shop/.+/cart,           roles: ROLE_CUSTOMER }
            - { path: ^/shop,                   roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

            - { path: ^/login$,                 roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/presence/check,         roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/users/current,          roles: [ROLE_ADMIN] }
            - { path: ^/users,                  roles: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN] }
            - { path: ^/action-log,             roles: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN] }
            - { path: ^/,                       roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ACCOUNT] }
```

In controller action is defined like:

```
    /**
 *
 * @Route("/{convention}/agenda/feed.xml", name="convention_agenda_feed")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Convention $convention
 * @return Response
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function agendaFeedAction(Request $request, Convention $convention): Response
{
```

There are no other annotations on controller.

I need to access page like **'localhost/22/agenda/feed.xml**' without logging in, but now when I open that page I am redirected immediatelly yo login page.

Comment: Do you mean to avail few routes for anonymous users e.g. Login, register etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Bceause this statement matches all routes:
{ path: ^/,  roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ACCOUNT] } and for all routes you need ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_ACCOUNT, you need to be more specific to avoid this. Something like ^/api that you have.